# std::vector<bool> - no data() function in specialization?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, std

I'm attempting to use a`data()` function found in virtually all other `std::vector` specializations, but I've come to find that there is no `data()` function for the `bool` specialization.

The documentation states:

> The specialization has the same member functions as the unspecialized
>   vector, except data, emplace, and emplace_back, that are not present
>   in this specialization.

What is the technical reason behind this?  Why could it not simply return a pointer to it's first element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` [is specialized for space-efficiency](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). It doesn't provide `data()` function.

You cannot address its elements because each of them is of 1 bit size, and there is nothing on machine like pointer to single bit.

> The manner in which std::vector is made space efficient (as well
>   as whether it is optimized at all) is implementation defined. One
>   potential optimization involves coalescing vector elements such that
>   each element occupies a single bit instead of sizeof(bool) bytes.

You can access its elements using

```
std::vector<bool>::reference
```

> This embedded class is the type returned by members of non-const
>   vector when directly accessing its elements. It accesses
>   individual bits with an interface that emulates a reference to a bool.

---

Normally `data()` returns a `T*` which here would be `bool*` but **IS NOT** because the `reference` and `pointer` types are not really references and pointers to `bool`. For example on my implementation bit type is a `typedef` for unsigned long

```
typedef unsigned long _Bit_type;
```

and this is what is used by a `reference` to bits called `struct _Bit_reference`. This struct is used by `struct _Bit_iterator` which is an *iterator* to elements. You can see here what it means to dereference this *iterator* and get element of `std::vector<bool>` on this implementation:

```
//  typedef unsigned long _Bit_type;
// struct _Bit_reference
// {
//   _Bit_type * _M_p;
// ...
// };
//  typedef _Bit_reference  reference;

reference
    _Bit_iterator::operator*() const
    { return reference(_M_p, 1UL << _M_offset); }
```

Comment: Even if each byte contained 8 "elements", isn't it a given that a pointer to the first element would be byte-aligned, and thus *would* be reliably addressable?

Comment: there is no pointer to bit. The smallest thing that machine can address is char

Comment: Right, but the *first element* would be byte-aligned, and thus could be accurately addressed, no?

Comment: std::vector<bool> even does not necessarily store its data in a single contiguous chunk of memory

Comment: @cmbasnett: Do you know if the _first element_ is a byte, 32-bit int, or 64-bit int? You don't because it's an implementation detail. What exactly should `data()` return?

Comment: normally it returns a T* which here would be bool* but IS NOT because the reference and pointer types are not really references and pointers to bool. In my implementation bit type is : typedef unsigned long _Bit_type;

Comment: @Blastfurnace I suppose that makes sense, ideally it would return a `void*`, but I suppose at that point it's useless since none of the implementation details are known.  Point taken.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yeah right. Which implementation doesn't store them contiguously? I guess char might be 14 bits and the floating point numbers might have the sign bit at bit 18, too?

Answer (score 1):

There can't be referencable `data` for particular bits. Maybe you're better off using `std::bitset<>` instead of specialized `std::vector<bool>` (which actually boils down to an equivalent of `std::vector<uint8_t>` specialization).